# Do we need to push compiled Solidity codes to GitHub?

Tags: solidity

I'm using this [extension](https://marketplace.visualstudio.com/items?itemName=JuanBlanco.solidity) in VS code to compile the Solidity code. This creates a new folder named `bin` in the parent directory which contains the compiled code.

[image]

So I need to ask if we need to ignore this folder while pushing codes to GitHub. And is there any recommended location within the project to keep the complied codes?

Answer (score 1):

If you work with normal SC, you do not need to put this bin folder to github, just add it to .gitignore.

However, if you're working with upgradable smart contract (https://docs.openzeppelin.com/learn/upgrading-smart-contracts), you have to keep this folder because it consists of the key/conditions to upgrade your SC later if needed. Normally, if you use hardhat compiler, you just keep it there:D. Also, of course, do not publish it to github.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'm using ABI from the compiled Solidity code, so if someone clones the repo in the future they have to specify the route of the abi, will it be fine?

Comment: Yes, no problem. Basically, they can generate their own abi from code or download it directly from blockchain scan.

Comment: Thanks, just can't upvote these cause I don't have a 15+ reputation.

Comment: No worry, glad for help :D, you can just resolve the question for others :D.